# How to put animated gif images and video behind the multiple vertical lines under the Canvas feature in the Html

Tags: html, canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLiMW.jpg)I am Derby. I am new in this community. I would need the help to run the video behind (under) the multiple vertical lines under the canvas in the html code. I would like to insert the style sheet (CSS) in the internal way that is under the same html page. Attached are the source code, and the page of the video displayed on the myCanvas on the second image, and display on my multiple vertical lines displayed on the myCanvas1 on the third image and video (test1.mp4) on the first image. I wish the images and source code would help you figure out the problem and offer the solutions based on your specialty. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video id="test" controls width="1080" autoplay>
 <source src="test1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1080" height="1920">
</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="1080" height="1920">
</canvas>

<script>
  const video = document.getElementById("test");
  const canvas= document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
  
function timerCallback() {
setTimeout(()=> {
timerCallback();
}, 0);
}; 

video.addEventListener("play", 
function() {var i= window.setInterval(function()
{ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,1080,1920)},timerCallback());}, false);
video.addEventListener("pause", function() {window.clearInterval(i);}, false);
video.addEventListener("ended", function() {clearInterval(i);}, false);
  


   const ctx1=document.getElementById("myCanvas1").getContext("2d");
   
   for (let i=5; i<=1080; i+=10) {
   
   ctx1.beginPath();
   ctx1.moveTo(i,0);
   ctx1.lineTo(i,1920);
   ctx1.lineWidth=5;
   ctx1.stroke();

 }

   
   
   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the video can run behind the multiple vertical lines in the Canvas of the html.